# Ptrace PEEKDATA IO error, address offset?

Tags: c, linux, memory-address, ptrace

I'm building a simple debugger, but when I use ptrace for PEEKDATA or POKEDATA I get an IO Error. Checked around some and think this is related to me using the objdump offset addresses for my address in the ptrace call, and not taking into account the base address of the process in memory.

[image: objdump]
This is the result of the objdump, I'm trying to set a breakpoint at 0x1158, so my ptrace call was originally:
`ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, child_pid, 0x1158, 0)`

This gave me the IO error. I then used pmap to find the offset in memory for the process and used this with the address, and I got no more error, but the data located on the address did not match the objdump. So what might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you still have the wrong address?